# Collapsing subgraph: Bogopolski's "Introduction to group theory"

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading Bogopolski's 'Introduction to group theory' and on page 127 the following maps are defined:

[image]

My confusion is about the expansion map. I get that the collapsing map is just collapsing trees in the forest to points. I have two questions:

1) From **exp($\tilde{v}$) = v** I would conclude that we simply copy vertices when expanding the graph $G/G_0$, however, expanding edges would introduce new vertices (since we need to take reduced paths in trees which were collapsed to points). This confuses me: does exp($\tilde{v}$)= v means that $\tilde{v}$ gets mapped to one $v$ or to all $v$ which are collapsed onto $\tilde{v}$?

2) I do not get the last line: **clearly col $\circ$ exp $=$ id, but exp $\circ$ col might not be the identity**. I drew multiple graphs, applied the collapsing map and then the expansion map, but always end up with the same graph as the one I started with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The expanding map is defined to have codomain $G$, which is the full original graph. However, not all vertices (nor edges) in the graph $G$ are in the range of $\exp$. (I'll demonstrate for vertices.) The definition of $G/G_0$ involved a choice of vertices $v_i \in T_i \subset G$; the vertex $\tilde{v}_i$ (which represents $T_i$ collapsed) will map to that particular chosen vertex $v_i$ only. The other vertices in $T_i$ will be in $G$, but will not be in the range of the expansion map.

In particular, this means that you shouldn't look at the expansion map as *defining* the graph which expands $G/G_0$; the codomain graph $G$ is defined before the expansion map is defined. In fact, if you had two different graphs $G$ and $H$ which both collapsed to the same graph $P$ (i.e., $G/G_0 \cong H/H_0 \cong P$), you can define two different expansion maps on $P$, one with codomain $G$ and one with codomain $H$. (You can even define two different expansion maps $G/G_0 \to G$ with the same codomain by changing the choice of vertices $v_i$.)

2) The answer to (1) should clarify this question. The codomain of exp$\circ$col is $G$, the same as its domain; so it's the same graph in the domain and codomain, which was verified by the examples you drew. However, the map applied to particular *vertices* (and edges) may not be the identity. (I'll demonstrate again for vertices.) If you start with some vertex $w_i \in T_i$ which is *not* the chosen vertex $v_i$, then exp$\circ$col$(w_i) = \exp(\tilde{v}_i) = v_i$, so the map exp$\circ$col does not return the input vertex $w_i$; thus it is not the identity.

Comment: For now I only have skimmed your answer, but I think I get what you mean. I will read it more carefully tomorrow! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Student You're welcome!